# Cron Expression recurring after every two week

Tags: java, spring, cron, cronexpression

I need to trigger my mail every alternate Monday and Wednesday. I am using Java Spring in my application. I have try using this cron expression `00 15 11 ? * MONDAY#1` and same for Wednesday, but it is triggering on 1 Monday and Wednesday of the month. What I want is it should trigger on Monday and Wednesday of first, third and fifth week of each month.

Can someone please help me in creating this cron expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
All type of cron exrpession you build from website [Cron Maker] 
I have one solution to meet with your requirement:
Algorithm:
1. Run cron every MON and WED day.


    eg. 0 0 12 ? * MON,WED * 
       Start time   Monday, September 7, 2015 6:10 AM Change
       Next 5 scheduled dates   
       a.   Monday, September 7, 2015 12:00 PM
       b.   Wednesday, September 9, 2015 12:00 PM
       c.   Monday, September 14, 2015 12:00 PM
       d.   Wednesday, September 16, 2015 12:00 PM
       e.   Monday, September 21, 2015 12:00 PM

2. Now pro-grammatically control on odd week. for eg in java


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
       if(c.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH) % 2 != 0) {
             //execute job
       } else {
             //not execute job just skip operation
       }
```

if i am able to made actual cron then i will post it.

Comment: I am not able to create cron expression for Monday and Wednesday of first, third and fifth week of each month in Cron Maker

Answer (score 1):

What you want is

```
00 15 11 ? * MONDAY#1,MONDAY#3,MONDAY#5,WEDNESDAY#1,WEDNESDAY#3,WEDNESDAY#5"
```

but I don't think it's going to work, because with #, only one expression is allowed. So, you'll have to have multiple cron entries, like the following.

```
00 15 11 ? * MONDAY#1
00 15 11 ? * MONDAY#3
00 15 11 ? * MONDAY#5
00 15 11 ? * WEDNESDAY#1
00 15 11 ? * WEDNESDAY#3
00 15 11 ? * WEDNESDAY#5
```

Comment: I tried this but it is triggering on first, third and fifth Monday and Wednesday of the month. I want it should trigger on Monday and Wednesday of first, third and fifth week of each month

Comment: I'm not really following you. This one triggers on 1st Monday, 3rd Monday, 5th Monday, 1st Wednesday, 3rd Wednesday, and 5th Wednesday of each month.